# Apply function that downloads zip files and deletes specific files

Tags: r, function, apply

I am trying to write a function and call it using `apply` to each row in my dataset. The dataset contains URLs of zip files, which will be downloaded, unzipped, and after unzipping TXT and zip files will be deleted from the working directory.

```
head(data)
                                                 data                                                                   URL
1 /files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip
2 /files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170424170430.zip http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170424170430.zip
3 /files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170417170423.zip http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170417170423.zip
4 /files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170410170416.zip http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170410170416.zip
5 /files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170403170409.zip http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170403170409.zip
6 /files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170327170402.zip http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170327170402.zip
```

My function:

```
Price_KASE <- function(data){
    URL = data[,2]
    dir = basename(URL)
    download.file(URL, dir)
    unzip(dir)
    TXT <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT")
    zip <- list.files(pattern = "*.zip")
    file.remove(TXT, zip)
}

    apply(data, 1, Price_KASE(data))
```

And the error message:

```
Error in download.file(URL, dir) : 
  'url' must be a length-one character vector
```

Please explain what is wrong with my code and how do I fix it? 
Thank you.

Alternative way using `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(data[,2])){
    URL = data[i, 2]
    dir = basename(URL)
    download.file(URL, dir)
    unzip(dir)
    TXT <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT")
    zip <- list.files(pattern = "*.zip")
    file.remove(TXT, zip)
}
```

It seems to work OK, but after 4th or 5th file I get `In download.file(URL, dir) :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170410170416.zip': HTTP status was '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'`

Comment: You're `apply`ing across rows, so it's passing each row as a vector to the function. Since each row is two elements, `download.file` doesn't know what to do. You either need to clean up your function to take a length two vector, or use `Map` and define a function with more than one parameter.

Comment: So, I separated out the column of URLs:

`URL = data[,2]
head(URL)
str(URL)


Price_KASE <- function(URL){
 
 dir = basename(URL)
 download.file(URL, dir)
 unzip(dir)
 TXT <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT")
 zip <- list.files(pattern = "*.zip")
 file.remove(TXT, zip)
}

apply(data, 1, Price_KASE(URL))`

Same error ...

Comment: What happens if you try this: `apply(data, 2, Price_KASE(data))`? So you apply the function for column, rather than for rows.

Comment: @sanyi14ka the same error

Comment: You need something like `Map(function(url, dat){....}, url = data$URL, dat = data$data)`

Comment: I just tried `?Map()` and got this page `http://127.0.0.1:18384/library/base/html/funprog.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your data frame your URLs are stored as factor variables. try using:

```
data[,2] <- as.character(data[,2])
```

if you are reading this as .csv or constructing the data frame, consider setting stringsAsFactors = FALSE.

**UPDATE:**

I noticed something when you try to use 1 in apply, it takes all of the lines a single vector. So you also have to change your function. Please see bold section below. This code runs completely in the example below giving the output.

```
data1 <- data.frame(a = "/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip",
                b = "http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip")


Price_KASE <- function(data){
  **URL = data[2]**
  dir = basename(URL)
  download.file(URL, dir)
  unzip(dir)
  TXT <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT")
  zip <- list.files(pattern = "*.zip")
  file.remove(TXT, zip)
}

data1$b <- as.character(data1$b)

apply(data1, 1, Price_KASE)

#     [,1]
#[1,] TRUE
#[2,] TRUE
```

Comment: But I have `> str(URL)
 chr [1:71] "http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip" ...`

Comment: When I convert it, to strings the functions runs on my R.

Comment: trying URL 'http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 42349 bytes (41 KB)
downloaded 41 KB

Comment: the problem may be coming up when it is on the variable data. Can you try > str(data)

Comment: Yeah ... well, I think `download.file()` aint grabbing the URL from the data correctly ...

Comment: Sure: `> str(data)
'data.frame':   71 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ data: Factor w/ 71 levels "/files/market_valuation/ru/2016/val160105160110.zip",..: 71 70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 ...
 $ URL : chr  "http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip" "http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170424170430.zip" "http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170417170423.zip" "http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170410170416.zip" ...
> `

Comment: as I said, when I copy the data, you provided in your question. It gets and downloads the data correctly.

Comment: Are you doing `as.character` or `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`?

Comment: I first generated a data.frame, then I converted them to character with as.character

Comment: Can you post your full code into the body of your answer, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143354/discussion-between-alihan-zihna-and-ak88).