# R error HTTP status was '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have to download several zip files from the website http://www.kase.kz/ru/marketvaluation

This question basically originates from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774949/apply-function-that-downloads-zip-files-and-deletes-specific-files) topic. Having not solved the problem as of now, I tried the following approach:

```
for (i in 1:length(data[,2])){
    URL = data[i, 2]
    dir = basename(URL)
    download.file(URL, dir)
    unzip(dir)
    TXT <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT")
    zip <- list.files(pattern = "*.zip")
    file.remove(TXT, zip)
}
```

Now I am facing another problem - after 4th or 5th trial R is giving me:

```
trying URL 'http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170403170409.zip'
Error in download.file(URL, dir) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170403170409.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(URL, dir) :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170403170409.zip': HTTP status was '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'
```

I don't know why this is happening. I would appreciate any suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, this was a piece of cake:

```
for (i in 1:length(data[,2])){
    URL = data[i, 2]
    dir = basename(URL)
    download.file(URL, dir)
    unzip(dir)
    TXT <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT")
    zip <- list.files(pattern = "*.zip")
    file.remove(TXT, zip)
    Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1))
}
```